# Install canvas fails using npm

Tags: macos, npm

I'm using macOS Mojave, Xcode 10.1. I'm struggling when running npm install canvas. node-gyp is 3.8.0 of mine.

```
npm WARN package.json babylon@5.5.29 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json babylon@5.5.29 No README data
npm WARN package.json babylon@5.5.29 No license field.
-
> canvas@1.3.12 install /Users/chuoi/project/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/canvas-postbuild.node
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/canvas-postbuild.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/chuoi/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/chuoi/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.1/bin/node" "/Users/chuoi/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/chuoi/project/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v4.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 18.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/chuoi/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.1/bin/node" "/Users/chuoi/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.1/bin/npm" "install" "canvas"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! canvas@1.3.12 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.3.12 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/chuoi/project/middleware/npm-debug.log
```

Could you help me on this cause it takes a whole day and I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your node version. Canvas doesn't support node 4.x.

"The minimum version of Node.js required is 6.0.0."

https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas